# PSN problems while trying to sign in

Tags: psn

I forgot my PSN password, and the email password associated with the account. I also have a new PS3. Does anybody have any idea how to find my password?

Comment: Without the password and the password of the email associated with the account, I doubt you can recover the account.

Comment: You might want to try recovering the email password first, then get access to your PSN account. I'm guessing Sony won't want to be super helpful if you can't get access to the email account.

Answer (score 1):

The only way would to be to contact customer support and convince them that it's yours, or make a new one. This is why I personally prefer PC gaming, because there's usually two step verification. Good luck!

Comment: Can you go into more detail? (ie. Say "Try include proof like X, Y and Z")